# validate before add to cart not working woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i have something i cant get working and i dont understand why.

I want to add some custom fields below a grouped product in woocommerce on the frontend.

So i have the following function (which works fine):

```
function add_data_opbouw_front(){
        global $woocommerce; global $post;
    $id = $post->ID;
    if ($id === 1411){
    $optiestijd = array();
    $optiesdag = array();
    $id = get_the_ID();
    $html = '<table><tbody>';
    $i=0;
    if( !empty(get_post_meta($id,'tijdslot',true) ) ){
                $html .= '<tr><td>Kies een tijd:</td><td><select name="tijdslot" required><option value="">Kies:</option>';
                $optiestijden = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'tijdslot',true);
                foreach ($optiestijden as $key=>$optie){
                $optiestijd[$optie] = 'Kies een tijdslot:';
                }
                foreach ($optiestijd as $optie => $label){
                    if(!empty($optie)){
                    $i++;
                $html .= '<option value="'.$optie.'"><span class="choiceoption">'. $optie.'</span></option>';
                    }
                }
                $html .= '</select></td></tr>';
        }
        if( !empty(get_post_meta($id,'dag',true) ) ){
                $optiesdagen = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'dag',true);
                $optiesdagen = explode('|',$optiesdagen);
                $html.= '<tr><td>Kies een dag:</td><td><select name="dag" required><option value="">Kies:</option>';
                foreach ($optiesdagen as $optie){
                    $i++;
                $html .= '<option value="'.$optie.'"><span class="choiceoption">'. $optie.'</span></option>';
                }
        }
                $html .= '</select></td></tr></tbody></table>';
                $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="voorraad_afname" value="1">';
        echo $html;
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button','add_data_opbouw_front', 35);
```

because i want to obligate user to pick a day and time, i want to validate before the add to cart and i do it like this:

```
function so_validate_add_cart_item( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = '', $variations= '' ) {
            global $woocommerce; global $post;
    $id = $post->ID;
    if ($id === 1411){

    // do your validation, if not met switch $passed to false
    if ( empty($_POST['tijdslot']) || empty($_POST['dag']) ){
        $passed = false;
        wc_add_notice( __( 'De velden "Kies een dag" en "Kies een tijdslot" zijn beiden verplicht', 'textdomain' ), 'error' );
        }
    }
    return $passed;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'so_validate_add_cart_item', 10, 5 );
```

But when I leave one of the select boxes empty, the product is being added to the cart anyway. So the validate doesnt throw in the error. I dont really understand why this is not working.
Any ideas?

Comment: _"But this is not working."_ doesn't say much of course. Do you get a certain error message? do you not see anything at all? 
From your question I understand that the result of the get_post_meta data is an array, can you give an example of what that data actually looks like? so that your question contains [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You are right, I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

After a long puzzle, i found out that approaching global $post is not working. Better is to approach the product_id. Because it is a grouped product, i checked wether one of the grouped products ID are in the add-to-cart like so:

```
$check = array('1398','1399','1400');
        if (in_array($product_id,$check)){
```

And that does work.

So updated code is:

```
function so_validate_add_cart_item( $passed, $product_id, $quantity, $variation_id = '', $variations= '' ) {
            $check = array('1398','1399','1400');
            if (in_array($product_id,$check)){
    
        // check if both selectboxes are used
        if ( empty($_POST['tijdslot']) || empty($_POST['dag']) ){
            $passed = false;
            wc_add_notice( __( 'De velden "Kies een dag" en "Kies een tijdslot" zijn beiden verplicht', 'textdomain' ), 'error' );
            }
        }
        return $passed;
    }
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'so_validate_add_cart_item', 10, 5 );
```